# Checking for the existence of a key in request.args in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am using Flask.

I am doing an ajax post and I need to check for the existence of a key

I tried the following, but it didn't work

```
if request.args.has_key('campaign_id_crid'):
        print True
```

What would be the right way to do that?

Comment: What doesn't work? What would be a 'better' way?

Comment: I dont know why it did not work.  I did an edit.  I did have an if.

Comment: Oh....I think it was an issue with the reloader.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Your example works fine in python 2.x code

Anyway, although `dict.has_key` is still about (in existing 2.x code - but removed in Python 3), it's generally considered more Pythonic to use the `in` operator such as:

```
if 'campaign_id_crid' in request.args:
    pass # do something
```

Comment: Actually `has_key` was removed in python3.

Comment: @Bakuriu Yup - I can see I didn't clarify enough... I meant "about" as in "still in the wild"... Edited, thanks.